# How to restrict yasnippet expand in certain environment only in emacs, for writing latex

Tags: emacs, latex

everyone. I was using emacs to write LaTeX and I want to use yasnippet to expand "FF" as "Fargues-Fontaine" only in **non-math** environment, that is to say, not between "$$", "\[\]" ,"\begin{displaymath}...\end{displaymath}". The following is the unfinished yasnippet file:

> # -- mode: snippet --
>
> # name: Fargues-Fontaine
>
> # key: FF
>
> # condition: ??
>
> # --
>
> Fargues-Fontaine

I am not familiar with emacs lisp languages. I searched through websites, only to find that I may use "# condition:" to do something. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot in advance.